# Notation question $|X^2|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am studying a little bit of set theory, and one of the questions in the book (in Efe A. Ok's real analysis book) asked to show that $\dim(X,\succeq)\leq |X^2|$, where $X$ is a finite set and $(X,\succeq)$ is a preorder.

Here is the full context:

> [image]

I'm having a little trouble interpreting the notation $|X^2|$. Would it mean the "total number of possible combinations of elements of $X^2$" or would it be 2, as in $|\mathbb{R}^2|$.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any set $S$, we have the following two notations:
$$|S|=\text{the cardinality of }S\qquad\qquad S^2=S\times S=\{(a,b):a,b\in S\}$$
Thus, $|X^2|$ is the cardinality of the set of ordered pairs of elements of $X$. which, incidentally, is equal to $|X|^2$. For example, if $X$ were a set with $2$ elements, then $|X^2|=4$.

Comment: Hey Zev! Thanks for the answer and for the edits! In this case wouldn't $|X^2|=n^2$ since $X$ is finite ($|X|=n,n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Indeed, we have $|X^2|=|X|^2$ (so if $n$ is the number of elements of $X$, then $|X^2|=n^2$).